# Connect and disconnect from a Bluetooth headset

Tags: ios, bluetooth, headset

I have paired my iPhone with a specific Bluetooth headset. I would like to programmatically connect and disconnect from the headset but cannot seem to find the API to accomplish this.

Am I simply missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no API to interact with Bluetooth headsets.

There are APIs for connecting to Bluetooth LE devices, called [`CoreBluetooth`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/CoreBluetooth_Framework.pdf). But these APIs cannot be used to connect to bluetooth headsets. Users have to use the settings application to connect to them.

Comment: Thanks DHamrick - at least I wasn't missing something. :)

Bummer. :(

Comment: how does Skype on iOS know that a headset is connected?